# Mongoose update an object in a nested array of object inside a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mongoose, mutation

i have this code :

```
const updateComment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
    const comment = post.comments.find(
      (comment) => comment.id === req.body.commentId
    );

    res.status(200).json(comment);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};
```

since i can't use mongoose `find` or `findById` because it's not a collection, i used javascript `find` method to find a specific comment, but since i can't also use `updateOne`, how can i update the comment body?

i tried this :

```
comment.body = req.body.newCommentBody;
```

but it doesn't work, how to mutate the object in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you're using unique commentId across all database (like ObjectId). Then you can use updateOne to search by comment id and use [positional operator $](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) like this:

```
await Post.updateOne(
{"comments.id" : req.body.commentId}, 
{"comments.$.body": req.body.newCommentBody}
)
```

But this way you won't get comment to send in res.
You can also find post, update in place and send back to db:

```
const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId)
const comment = post.comments.find(
      (comment) => comment.id === req.body.commentId
    );
comment.body = req.body.newCommentBody
await post.save()

 res.status(200).json(comment);
```

I'm not sure if .findById() returns array or single doc, if array you have to add `[0]` of course.